# Why Toast.makeText and not new Toast

Tags: android, toast, android-source

This is may be a noob question, but I was wondering why do we have to use a static method (makeText) to create a Toast and not a constructor.

Why do we have to use this:

```
makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)
```

instead of this:

```
new Toast(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)
```

This is the makeText method:

```
    public static Toast makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration) {
        Toast result = new Toast(context);

        LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflate.inflate(com.android.internal.R.layout.transient_notification, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.message);
        tv.setText(text);

        result.mNextView = v;
        result.mDuration = duration;

        return result;
    }
```

Why don't we have the following:

```
public Toast (Context context, CharSequence text, int duration) {
    this(context);

    LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflate.inflate(com.android.internal.R.layout.transient_notification, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.message);
    tv.setText(text);

    this.mNextView = v;
    this.mDuration = duration;
}
```

I searched the web and source code for any reason but I didn't find.

Please if you have an idea, don't hesitate.

Comment: Maybe because it's easier to use a static method and we don't have to create a Toast object? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question basically drill downs to when should I make a method static. The answer is simple- when your method has a very specific task and does not change the state of the object.

Something like a utility method, say add(int a, int b) which simply returns a+b. If I need to store the value a+b for later use for the object, static method is strictly no-no (you will not be able to store a non static variable in a static method). But if we are dealing with some action which is independent of state of the object, static is the answer.

Why are we giving preference to static if it is independent of state of object?

1. Memory- static method will only have one copy, irrespective of the actual number of object.
2. Availability- Method is available even if you don't have single object

Ofcourse the downside is that we are keeping a copy of method even if we do not use it at all (if it was non-static and no object was created, we would have saved this space). But this is of lower weight than the advantages mentioned above.

As the method we are discussing here (makeText), does not need to maintain a state for later use, the best way to go is static method.

--Edit--

The answer mentioned above is more generic as to when we should use static and when non-static, let me get specific to Toast class.

Toast class gives us 2 ways to create a Toast object (Refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html)

1. makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration) which returns a Toast object which the values assigned.
2. Normal way, use new Toast(context) to create an object, then set values as required.

If you use method 1, you are saying something like Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show(); and we are done. I use this method all the time.

Method 2 is used only for a specific case, from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

> Do not use the public constructor for a Toast unless you are going to
>   define the layout with setView(View). If you do not have a custom
>   layout to use, you must use makeText(Context, int, int) to create the
>   Toast.

@CFlex, If I got your question properly, I guess you just want to know why we have Toast.makeText(context, text, duration) returning a Toast object, when the same thing could have been done by a constructor.

Whenever I look at something like ClassName.getObject returning object of class, I think about singleton pattern. Well, in this case we are not exactly talking about singleton, I would like to assume that makeText returns same object always (to save creation of N objects), otherwise it is just a fancy thing developed by Android team.

Comment: @Kamal Ok I think I got it, but why didn't they make just a Toast.showText(Context, String, int) ? Because we can Toast t = Toast.makeText(...); as well as we can new Toast(context, text, dur).show();  I find the makeText method just useless. why didn't they do just others Ctor or a shows methods. I don't know if I'm clear enough.

Comment: @CFlex, please see my Edit, I hope that gives some explanation. We cannot say anything for sure unless we see the source code, but the use of singleton pattern (same object to save creation of N objects), seems to be most likely answer for use of a static method returning object.

Comment: @Kamal Yes I thought about singleton too, but as you said it's not (a new instance is created each time with the Toast result = new Toast(context); /*...*/ return result;  I would agree with you with the fact that it's a fancy thing. I think they wanted to make the difference between the 2 ways to use toast. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

One rule: Ask yourself "Does it make sense to call this method, even if no object has been constructed yet?" If so, it should definitely be static.

Remember that objects live in memory and they are created for certain jobs. Static methods are available for all the objects in a class and it is not necessary to create an object to use them.

So there is no reason to create an object Toast to be able to access the method `makeText`, when you can access it as a static method (more elegant and compact)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know:

That's because we don't wish to hold an instance of the object toast, which would require an amount of memory persistently used until cleaned by the GarbageCollector.

And that it always have access to being displayed, so it is not required by your application to have any set of permissions.